# How to save image in gallery in API 29 in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-image, mediastore

From API 29 `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` are deprecated.

I used the following code to save an image file to a specific folder in internal storage  :

```
  private fun saveFile(applicationContext: Context, file: File){
    val folder  = "/customFolder"
    try {
        val destFile = File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}${folder}/${file.name}")
        FileUtils.copyFile(file,destFile) 

        val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
        val contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file)!!
        mediaScanIntent.data = contentUri
        applicationContext.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)

    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
    } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
    }
}
```

Reference link for `FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile,File destFile)` - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)

After updating to API 29 above code doesn't work. How to modify  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` for API 29 ?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html

Answer (score 1):

This will work, This will store your file in app specified folder , you can user MediaStorage as well to store img in gallery , the new functions are now getFilesDir()
getExternalFilesDir(), getCacheDir(),getExternalCacheDir(),

```
String path = ApplicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)+Foldername+filename;
File file = new File(path);
file.getParentFile().mkdir();
 try {
            OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            savedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```